# How to change time list step 30 min and 60 min into dropdown of time_field in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to time list dropdown 30,60. I have time list 01,02,03 into image. I have my code:

```
<%= f.time_field :end_date, :step=>1800,:class=>"form-control ml-2",required: true %>
```

[image: I have time list image.Please click image show]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for posting. SO's policy suggests that you share your research efforts: what code reference did you look at? What solutions did you already try? Why didn't you find a solution or why the solutions you tried did not work? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the steps option you need to use `f.time_select` instead of `f.time_field`.

So you could do something like:

```rb
<%= f.time_select :end_date, { minute_step: 30 }, class: 'form-control ml-2', required: true %>
```